# How to display a some records in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm beginner in .net.

I need to display a some records in CheckedListBox.

I have table (Cat) in DataSet:

[image]

I need to display the content of the data table (color column) in CheckedListBox control.

How can it can be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [CheckedListBox does not support binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8216010/897326), so this will not work as expected:

```
CheckedListBox1.DataSource = tempDataSet.Tables("Cat")
CheckedListBox1.DisplayMember = "Color"
CheckedListBox1.ValueMember = "ID"
```

You can use a [Bindable CheckedListBox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14916/Bindable-CheckedListBox) instead. Then you can bind at design time using the Properties window:

[image]

Comment: Neolisk that would actually work if you were to do the following 
((ListBox)CheckedListBox1).DataSource =tempDataSet.Tables("Cat");
((ListBox)CheckedListBox1).DisplayMember = "Color";
((ListBox)CheckedListBox1).ValueMember = "ID; I would personally look at BindingList

Comment: @DJKRAZE: DataSource and similar are not suggested by intellisense, but they are available, so compiler won't stop you, it will even correct the case for you, without casting to ListBox. People are reporting issues with CheckedListBox though, when binding through DataSource. [Here is one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4009/Workaround-for-disappearing-checks-in-the-CheckedL).

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this link:

[how to bind data in checkedlistbox in window application](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/307681/how-to-bind-data-in-checkedlistbox-in-window-appli)

or try this template:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT NAME AC_CODE FROM AccountM where compcode='" + Compcls.Gcomp_cd + "'", con);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "AccountM ");
checkedListBox1.DataSource = ds;

checkedListBox1.SelectedValue = "AC_CODE";
checkedListBox1.SelectedItem = "NAME";
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say if you save the `checkedListBox1.SelectedValu`e in db you can do as follow:

1. Load you data into a data table, e.g. `myDt`
2. Loop each datarow in your datatable & set the checked status based on `dr` value

   ```
   foreach (DataRow dr in myDt.Rows)
   {
        checkedListBox1.SelectedValue = dr[0].ToString();
        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex, true);
   }
   ```

Hope this helps...